# Adding indexes to a mesh

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I'm trying to figure out how to add indexes to a shape that already has all of its vertices. I can see by the vertices that I have them all where I need them but I have a weird artifact caused by the indexes not being added properly. However I'm not sure how to add them correctly.

```
Surface::Surface()
{
    int size = 200;
    ofPoint p1(0, 0, 0), p2(0, 0, size), p3(size, 0, size), p4(200, 0, 0);

    s1 = new Curve(p1, p2);
    s2 = new Curve(p2, p3);
    s3 = new Curve(p4, p3);
    s4 = new Curve(p1, p4);

    for(double i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        for(double j = 0; j <= size; j++){
            mesh.addVertex(getPoint(i, j));
        }
    }

    int width = size, height = size;
    for (int y = 0; y<=height; y++){
        for (int x=0; x<=width; x++){
            mesh.addIndex(x+y*width);
            mesh.addIndex((x+1)+y*width);
            mesh.addIndex(x+(y+1)*width);

            mesh.addIndex((x+1)+y*width);
            mesh.addIndex((x+1)+(y+1)*width);
            mesh.addIndex(x+(y+1)*width);
        }
    }
}
```

What draw vertices gives:

[image]

But the indexes are connecting too many dots and I'm unsure which ones how the indexes should be connected. Drawing the wireframe:

[image]

Maybe this issue is proper to concave shapes? Everyone seems to do more or less the same thing for when they want to add indexes to a mesh

Answer (score 1):

You add size+1 vertices in each dimension:

```
for(double i = 0; i <= size; i++){
    for(double j = 0; j <= size; j++){
        mesh.addVertex(getPoint(i, j));
    }
}
```

But then index size+2 vertices in each dimension as x and y can equal size, and within the loop you add 1:

```
int width = size, height = size;
for (int y = 0; y<=height; y++){
    for (int x=0; x<=width; x++){
        mesh.addIndex(x+y*width);
        mesh.addIndex((x+1)+y*width);
        mesh.addIndex(x+(y+1)*width);

        mesh.addIndex((x+1)+y*width);
        mesh.addIndex((x+1)+(y+1)*width);
        mesh.addIndex(x+(y+1)*width);
    }
}
```

This will result in garbage vertices being indexed. To fix simply change the loop condition to < width and < height.

```
int width = size, height = size;
for (int y = 0; y<height; y++){
    for (int x=0; x<width; x++){
        mesh.addIndex(x+y*width);
        mesh.addIndex((x+1)+y*width);
        mesh.addIndex(x+(y+1)*width);

        mesh.addIndex((x+1)+y*width);
        mesh.addIndex((x+1)+(y+1)*width);
        mesh.addIndex(x+(y+1)*width);
    }
}
```

Conceptually you need to create one less primitive than vertex. The simplest form to imagine is if size == 1. You need to create 2 vertices but only 1 quad.

Comment: It makes more sense now, but its still adding too many indexes. It's like for the lines that should do points 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 it adds a last line from 4 to 1. I tried lowering the mount of times each for loop executes but it doesn't seem to help. Without modification, with your code it looks like this: http://imgur.com/N8WIRIN

Comment: Yes sorry, I've edited the answer. You should just need to change the condition of your loop to < rather than <=.Conceptually you need to create one less primitive than vertex. If you imagine you create a quad between each pair of vertices. The simplest form to imagine is if size == 1. You need to create 2 vertices but only 1 quad.

Comment: I figured something like that and I had already tried something similar to your edit before you did it. And the result is the same. I believe however that I'm not adding the indexes in the order you think I'm adding them. For example, if I change my for loops to `y<height - 10` and `x<height - 10`, I get this: http://imgur.com/llGGYn2

Comment: Something else to note, if I zoom in into the wireframe of the top-part of the shape, I can clearly see the standard rectangle with a diagonal that is the 2 triangles being used for the wireframe. However, if I zoom into the lower part, the one I don't want, I only see straight lines. Here I found an angle where you can see the effect (from the inside looking out): http://imgur.com/ZqSpkwm

Comment: I don't know then, perhaps the problem lies in the getPoint() method? It might be generating incorrect vertex positions?

Comment: Well the points are in the right position, aren't they? Otherwise I wouldn't be getting the 1st image when I ask to draw vertices, no?